# I can connect to On-Premise Sharepoint, but all Get- Commands return error 403

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I do the following:

```
$url = 'https://oo.de/websites/it'
$sncred = Get-StoredCredential -Target PnPPS:SPCredentials
$Global:snPnPConn = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Credentials $sncred -TransformationOnPrem -CurrentCredential -ReturnConnection 
# Does run, but the next one gives 403-Error
Get-PnpList
Get-PnPList : Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (403) Unzulässig.
```

How can I debug this?
According to the Admin of my site, I do have full  access rights  on the Site.
I can open the site in browser.
All Help  in Internet is to AzureAD(?!).

```
$snPnpConn:
>ConnectionType                         : O365
>InitializationType                     : Unknown
>Scopes                                 :
>PSCredential                           :
>ClientId                               : 31359c7f-bd7e-475c-86db-fdb8c937548e
>ClientSecret                           :
>ApplicationInsights                    : PnP.PowerShell.ALC.ApplicationInsights
>Url                                    : https://foo.de/websites/it
>TenantAdminUrl                         :
>Certificate                            :
>DeleteCertificateFromCacheOnDisconnect : False
>Context                                : PnP.Framework.PnPClientContext
>Tenant                                 :
>AzureEnvironment                       : Production
```

Comment: Shouldn't you tell it what connection to use? `Get-PnPList -Connection $Global:snPnPConn`.  BTW. Why is that connection variable scoped `global:` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The Connect-PnPONline gives a context, which is in my opinion global. 
And I tried it with the -Connection switch -> the same result.

Comment: Then you need to try out a different username/password because the one you now use doesn't seem to have enough privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into the same problem. My solution was to Uninstall PnP.PowerShell module and install the legacy SharePointPnPPowerShell2019 module. The legacy module isn't being maintained, but the newer version doesn't support on-premise installations. There is some confusion about this, and there were attempts made to get PnP.PowerShell to work with on-prem (the -TransformationOnPrem flag). But Microsoft documentation as of May 2022 says that PnP.PowerShell doesn't support on-premise farms: [PnP PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/benefits-of-using-powershell-with-sharepoint#pnp-powershell-patterns--practices).

From PowerShell, run "Uninstall-Module PnP.PowerShell". Once that completes, run "Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2019" (or 2016 or 2013, depending on your version of SharePoint.

After I got the legacy module installed, I was able to successfully run commands like Get-PnPList without the 403 errors.

Comment: That did the trick. From PowerShell, run "Uninstall-Module PnP.PowerShell". Once that completes, run "Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2019" (or 2016 or 2013, depending on your version of SharePoint. After I got the legacy module installed, I was able to successfully run commands like Get-PnPList without the 403 errors.

Answer (score 0):

For all who need this connection mode for transforming pages to modern, you have to use PowerShell 7.0+. Then Connect-PnPOnline (PnP.PowerShell) works for connect to SharePoint on-premise.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).